# "if a=b elif a !=b" doesn't work

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, if-statement

I have a table (named table) made of Nbin lists, each one of them containing Nbin elements. Some of those elements are (long) arrays, all the other elements are single 0s.
Then I made this short code:

```
a=1
b=1
Nbin=3
for a in range(1,Nbin+1):
    for b in range(1,Nbin+1):
        if np.all(table[a][b]!=0) and np.all(a = b):
            s2=11 
            print a,'-',b,s2
        elif np.all(table[a][b]!=0) and np.all(a != b):
            s2=12 
            print a,'-',b,s2
```

Basically, the output I am expecting (for Nbin=3) is:

```
1 - 1 11
1 - 2 12
1 - 3 12
2 - 2 11
2 - 3 12
3 - 3 11
```

but what I get is:

```
1 - 1 11
1 - 2 11
1 - 3 11
2 - 2 11
2 - 3 11
3 - 3 11
```

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: do you mean `==`?

Comment: You know that `a = b` is an assignment? You realize that `np.all(a != b)` and `np.all(a == b)` can be both `False`?

Comment: Why are you using `np.all` in your conditionals? You're only testing one conditional at a time, so you don't need `np.all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, as the comments have pointed out, that your first conditional contains an assignment, not a comparison.  `a = b` sets `a`'s value to `b`, while what you want is `a == b`, which says whether or not the two values are equal.  `np.all(a = b)` will always evaluate to true so long as `b` is not 0.

Also, for this conditional you don't need `np.all`.  `a == b` and `a != b` is sufficient.

Note that I cannot guarantee your code will now work as expected, since you have not said what the value of `table` is.

Comment: Thank you very much! As you might have infered I am new to coding in Python, the problem was exactly that I wrote = insted of == (and of course the np.all was useless). Now it works perfectly!!